# Robohelp install, Tomcat issues

Tags: tomcat

I have a co-worker whose been trying to get Robohelp working on a windows 2003 server. They followed the instructions for installing the product but when we try to connect to the robohelp admin with the default login of admin/admin we get a message that says:
Login Error : Unable to connect to database. Kindly refer tomcat logs for details.

The log gives the following exception:
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'TSetting'.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.DatabaseManager.TestDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:854)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.DatabaseManager.isConnected(DatabaseManager.java:347)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.AuthAgent.AuthenticateUser(AuthAgent.java:168)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.AuthAgent.Authenticate(AuthAgent.java:68)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.RoboHelpServer.doGet(RoboHelpServer.java:155)
 at adobe.robohelp.server.RoboHelpServer.doPost(RoboHelpServer.java:206)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Of course, there's no object by the name of TSetting.

The SQL Server is 2005. Are there any known issues with this or items I can look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was because the trial was being installed. Once the full product was installed the issue went away.